# Carriwerwave with Rails 5 errors on console

Tags: carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-console

While working with rails 5.0.0.1 and using carriwerave even using:

`gem 'carrierwave', '>= 1.0.0.beta', '< 2.0'`

or

`gem 'carrierwave'`

When I'm trying to run `rails g uploader somthing` it responds with:
*Could not find generator 'uploader'. Maybe you meant 'model', 'helper' or 'mailer'*

And actually it isn't in my rails generators.

Also if I create the file manually, it works well on development, but when I try to instantiate my model in my rails console it shows me:

`NameError: uninitialized constant Something::AttachmentUploader`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`? And make sure your `Gemfile.lock` reflects the gem versions you want?

Comment: Yup, I've tried, this is pretty weird otherwise I wouldn't create a question on stackoverflow, but thanks man!